# Mapping useState array into input fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to map out the values in a state to make a dynamic input list. However, I am not quite sure how to correctly map it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

This is what I got:

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";

const Values = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([
    { name: "sean", income: 0, spending: 0, investment: 0 },
    { name: "bobby", income: 0, spending: 0, investment: 0 },
    { name: "katie", income: 0, spending: 0, investment: 0 },
    { name: "mary", income: 0, spending: 0, investment: 0 },
    { name: "elly", income: 0, spending: 0, investment: 0 },
  ]);

  const allIncome = "adding up all the values of income here";

  return (
    <form className="box">
      {values.map(() => (
        <div className="container">
          <div>{values.name}</div>
          <input
            type="number"
            value={values.income}
            onChange={(e) => setValues({ income: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            value={values.spending}
            onChange={(e) => setValues.apply({ spending: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            value={values.investment}
            onChange={(e) => setValues({ investment: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Values;
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do brother

Answer (score 2):

For situations like this I recommend using a Higher Order Function to close over an `id` property, or an index if you aren't deleting or sorting records, in an `onChange` callback so you can uniquely identify the array element you want to update. From here you use the typical input `name` and `value` to apply the update.

Example:

```
const changeHandler = index => event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setValues(values => values.map((el, i) => index === i 
    ? {
        ...el,
        [name]: value,
      }
    : el,
  ));
};
```

When mapping the data you attach the callback and pass the current index. You should reference the current `value` element when passing/setting the `value` prop on each input, referencing the nested property of each data element. Don't forget to add a React key to the outermost mapped element

```
<form className="box">
  {values.map((value, index) => ( // <-- current element value and index
    <div
      key={index} // <-- add React key
      className="container"
    >
      <div>{value.name}</div> // <-- reference from current value
      <input
        type="number"
        name="income" // <-- name matches state field
        value={value.income}
        onChange={changeHandler(index)} // <-- add callback, pass current index
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        name="spending"
        value={value.spending}
        onChange={changeHandler(index)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        name="investment"
        value={value.investment}
        onChange={changeHandler(index)}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Ideally, your data would have a dedicated GUID, such as an `id` property. This is preferable to using the index as the index isn't an intrinsic property of your data. The reason being is that now you can delete, sort, etc... the `values` array and the React key being the `id` of the element React can optimize rerendering the UI. See [Lists & Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more in-depth explanation.

Updater using an id property:

```
const changeHandler = id => event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setValues(values => values.map((el) => el.id === id 
    ? {
        ...el,
        [name]: value,
      }
    : el,
  ));
};

...

<form className="box">
  {values.map((value) => ( // <-- current element value
    <div
      key={value.id} // <-- add React key
      className="container"
    >
      <div>{value.name}</div> // <-- reference from current value
      <input
        type="number"
        name="income"
        value={value.income}
        onChange={changeHandler(value.id)} // <-- add callback, pass current id
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        name="spending"
        value={value.spending}
        onChange={changeHandler(value.id)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        name="investment"
        value={value.investment}
        onChange={changeHandler(value.id)}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```